# Orange reading in new features from Tab-Delimited File

Tags: orange

In my tab delimited file I have 65 features and 1 target variable that are numerical and continuous. My data is supposed to be used for regression models. There should be 65 features and 1 target variable in the columns when I upload the file to orange.

However,there are actually 68 features, 2 new features called "Feature 1" and "Feature 2" show up that shouldn't be there. Both of them are categorical. Why are these two new features showing up? I counted the amount of variables I put and the amount of domain and attribute types corresponding to each variable. They both add up to 66 so I don't know where the extra features are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This should usually not happen. It can only happen if there are some stray entries in columns, columns following the penultimate(last) column of your data. Please check. This usually happens while preparing data. Please let me know if I have solved your problem.